# Python - remove one dictionary by key:value related to other value from list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, duplicates

I have list of dictionaries like below:

```
my_dict = [{'name': 'weather', 'result': 'good'}, {'name': 'weather', 'result': 'bad'}, {'name': 'weather', 'result': 'average'}, {'name': 'wind', 'result': 'strong'}, {'name': 'water', 'result': 'high'}]
```

As you can see all dictionaries have the same key pairs ('name' and 'result') but different values. I'd like to keep all dictionaries except the ones with 'name': 'weather' and 'result' != 'good'

Result should look like:

```
my_dict = [{'name': 'weather', 'result': 'good'}, {'name': 'wind', 'result': 'strong'}, {'name': 'water', 'result': 'high'}]
```

I can do it by naive method - but is there a more sophisticated method like comprehension or filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method that uses `filter` is as below:

```
list(filter(lambda x: not (x['name'] == 'weather' and x['result'] != 'good'), my_dict))
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'weather', 'result': 'good'},
 {'name': 'wind', 'result': 'strong'},
 {'name': 'water', 'result': 'high'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
new_dicts = [
    d for d in my_dicts 
    if not (d.get('name') == 'weather' and d.get('result') != 'good')
]
```

Has the benefit of gracefully handling situations where for some reason the expected keys (`weather` and/or `result`) are missing. `dict.get()` returns `None` by default, if the key is missing. Accessing the value by key directly with `__getitem__` (the `[]`-notation) throws a `KeyError`, when the key is missing.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
a = [d for d in my_dict if not (d['name'] == 'weather' and d['result'] != 'good')]
```

For each element in the array (a dictionary) select it if the name is 'weather' and the the result is anything but 'good'.

This is a particular good candidate for a comprehension.

Comment: Doesn’t this give the inverse result?

Comment: The `if`  condition should be in `not`

Comment: or use DeMorgan.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is inversing the result as @quamrana said

Comment: Code has been fixed.  It now gice sthe result for the OP.  Only needed the not

Answer (score 0):

At this point it's a bit redundant with all the other answers but here's another syntax:

```
new_dict = [d for d in my_dict if d['name'] != 'weather' or d['result'] == 'good']
```

And the result:

```
[{'name': 'weather', 'result': 'good'},
 {'name': 'wind', 'result': 'strong'},
 {'name': 'water', 'result': 'high'}]
```